# Date API with JavaScript doesn't work

Tags: javascript, date

I want to get date **Jan/1/2015**.

So, I tried this :

```
new Date(2015,1,1)
```

However,I got **Jan/31/2015** or **Feb/1/2015.**

What does it take for me to get date: **Jan/1/2015?**

**Chrome**

[image: Chrome]

**FireFox**

[image: FireFox]

**InternetExplorer**

[image: InternetExplorer]

Comment: Do you know what argument Date object accept ?

Comment: Sorry, I do not know.Can I teach me this.

Comment: Look the below answers I guess you got that what I was trying to say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Months begin at 0. You are also getting some confusion due to timezones and whether midnight belongs to this day or previous day.

new Date(2015, 0, 1, 0, 0);

Answer (score 1):

Months are zero-indexed so try `new Date(2015,0,1)`. Month '0' is January, Month '1' is February up to 11 for December.

From the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) website:

> month
>
> ```
> Integer value representing the month, beginning with 0 for January to 11 for December.
> ```

Days start from 1 up to the relevant maximum for a given month.